# How display file path at bottom in "All My Files" on Sierra 10.12.3?

Tags: finder, path

On older versions of macOS there used to be a file path at the bottom of "All My Files" so you could see where the files were located & click to path if wanted.

Here's a random example I found online:

[image: All My Files in Finder]

(file path can be seen at very bottom)

How can I enable this on Sierra (10.12.3)?

Answer (score 5):

The one you reference in the screenshot can be enabled in either of the following two ways:

**Using the Mouse**

1. Ensure the Finder is active
2. Go to the View menu
3. Select the Show Path Bar option

**Using the keyboard**

You can also use the following keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

You may not be aware, but you can also customise the Finder Toolbar to include a Path button. To do this:

1. Ensure the Finder is active
2. Go to the View menu
3. Select the Customise Toolbar... option
4. Drag the Path icon to your toolbar
5. Click on Done

**Note:** The icon looks like: [image: The path icon looks like:]

Comment: One thing about turning on the path bar is that it's then on **everywhere** --- in the past it seemed to only be on (for me) in "all my files", unless I'm mistaken. Is there a way to re-create this? (or maybe it was just in search(?))

Comment: Pretty sure that's how it's always been, at least for a while now. It's also the reason I don't use it and opt instead for the path button in the Finder toolbar - I just click on that to view the path when I need to. For me that's a better option, although it took me a little while to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the file path at any time without changing any preferences. Just 
command-click the proxy icon in the title bar of the window.

[image: file path displayed from title bar]

The file path appears just like it would when using the file path icon. The great thing is that this doesn't just work in the Finder -- it will work in most applications in which you have a file open in a window.